# How should I set Routers to let my PC connet other PCs in a LAN?

Tags: networking, router

Now I am in a LAN which structure is as below:

1. My LAN is a corparate network;
2. Most PC are connected to switch -- "X" to connect internet;
3. Router "A" connect to switch --"X";
4. My computer and other 4 PCs(defined as PC_1/2/3/4) connect to Router "A";
5. Router "A" are not used in "switch mode" and its makes: TP-LINK, its modes:TL-WR842N;
6. Now I find my PC just can connect PC_1/2/3/4 which connect router "A" rather than other PCs which connect to switch "X";

Now how shall I set to let my PC and all other PCs can connect each others in all over my corporate LAN?

Comment: Hello vx. Your router naming has me a bit confused. Do you mean router A connects to routers A1 & A2, and they are meant to talk to each other through router A? Also, if possible would you be able to provide the model of the routers?

Comment: Routers segment LANs... Are these soho type routers like Netgear, Linksys, D-Link, etc or REAL routers like enterprise grade stuff? Without more knowledge of your layout, structure, and need, I can only guess you don't need 6 routers, but need one and 5 switches... Trying to make one big LAN with 6 routers is like walking across a tight rope... You might make it, but your gonna fall a lot until you learn all the tricks. If this was 2, or maybe even 3,  routers I'd guide you... 6 is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you; I know I little about LAN; and I give the information which has something wrong;

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you; I know a little about LAN; and I give the above information which has something wrong; I just check our LAN with admin, and know that most PCs are connected by switches, and Router A connect to this Switch and my PC connect Router A(tp-link:TL-WR842N); Now I find my PC just can connect PCs which connect to Router A and can't connect PCs which connect Switch; How shall I set LAN to let my PC connect to all PCs in LAN? or shall I set Router A as Switch to do that?

Comment: Is this a corporate network? Are you using the routers in switch mode? Can you [edit] the question to include the makes and models?

Comment: I have edit it; Sorry for some confused.